# How do I map a geometry column to a POCO?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, postgis, npgsql

I have the following column...

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_place ADD COLUMN "Geometry" geometry(Point, 4326);
```

How do I map this to a property on a POCO? Or, to put it another way, what should be the type of this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set POCO property's type to `byte []` and mapped my entity to a view, which wraps the original table and converts the Geometry column to a `bytea` using...

```
st_asbinary(tbl_place."Geometry") AS "Geometry"
```

Otherwise, its disconcerting to discover that one's app is built around an OR Mapper that won't map. It makes you make your data conform to the mapper rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "DbGeometry" type in poco class :

```
public DbGeometry Geometry{ get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that can't work with EF 6 because Npgsql returns an instance of PostgisPoint from the database.